# Attaching libumem is causing process to receive SIGKILL (Signal 9)

Tags: memory-leaks, sigkill, libumem

I have a need to check for memory leak in a Java application that uses JNI (C++ Code) a lot.
When I attach libumem, the process exits after receiving a SIGKILL (Signal 9).

When does a process receive SIGKILL?
How is libumem causing it?

OS: Solaris 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solaris 8, Does NOT have libumem by default! Thus the program was not able to startup at all.